# Google Analytics custom Variable is not working fine with ios

Tags: ios, ios4, google-analytics, google-analytics-api

I am using Google Analytics with ios, and i want to update number of custom variable as soon as viewDidAppear called, here is my code.

```
for (int i = 0 ; i < [KeyArray count]; i++) {
        error = nil;
        if ([KeyArray objectAtIndex:i] == @"Carat") {
            NSDictionary *caratDict = [selectedDiamondsFilter objectForKey:[KeyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Carat From %@ to %@",[caratDict objectForKey:@"caratfrom"],[caratDict objectForKey:@"caratto"]];
            NSLog(@"%@",value);
            if (![[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1 name:@"Carat" value:value scope:kGANVisitorScope withError:&error]) {
                NSLog(@"carat =%@",error);
            }

            if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Diamond Sort" action:@"Sort selected" label:@"sort" value:-1 withError:nil]){
                NSLog(@"Not able to track for Diamonds Section");
            }
            [[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch];

        }
        else if ([KeyArray objectAtIndex:i] == @"Clarity") {
            NSDictionary *caratDict = [selectedDiamondsFilter objectForKey:[KeyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Clarity From %@ to %@",[caratDict objectForKey:@"clarityfrom"],[caratDict objectForKey:@"clarityto"]];
            NSLog(@"%@",value);
            [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1 name:@"Clarity" value:value scope:kGANVisitorScope withError:&error];
            if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Diamond Sort" action:@"Sort selected" label:@"sort" value:-1 withError:nil]){
                NSLog(@"Not able to track for Diamonds Section");
            }

        }
        else if ([KeyArray objectAtIndex:i] == @"Color") {
            NSDictionary *caratDict = [selectedDiamondsFilter objectForKey:[KeyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Color From %@ to %@",[caratDict objectForKey:@"colorfrom"],[caratDict objectForKey:@"colorto"]];
            NSLog(@"%@",value);
            [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1 name:@"Color" value:value scope:kGANVisitorScope withError:&error];
            if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Diamond Sort" action:@"Sort selected" label:@"sort" value:-1 withError:nil]){
                NSLog(@"Not able to track for Diamonds Section");
            }

        }
        else if ([KeyArray objectAtIndex:i] == @"Price") {
            NSDictionary *caratDict = [selectedDiamondsFilter objectForKey:[KeyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            NSString *value = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"Price From %@ to %@",[caratDict objectForKey:@"pricefrom"],[caratDict objectForKey:@"priceto"]];
            NSLog(@"%@",value);
            [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1 name:@"Price" value:value scope:kGANVisitorScope withError:&error];
            if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Diamond Sort" action:@"Sort selected" label:@"sort" value:-1 withError:nil]){
                NSLog(@"Not able to track for Diamonds Section");
            }

        }
        else if ([KeyArray objectAtIndex:i] == @"Shape") {
            NSArray *shapes = [selectedDiamondsFilter objectForKey:[KeyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            for (int i = 0; i<[shapes count]; i++) {
                [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1 name:@"Shape" value:[shapes objectAtIndex:i] scope:kGANVisitorScope withError:&error];
                NSLog(@"%@",[shapes objectAtIndex:i]);
                if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Diamond Sort" action:@"Sort selected" label:@"sort" value:-1 withError:nil]){
                    NSLog(@"Not able to track for Diamonds Section");
                }

            }
            NSLog( @"%@",shapes);

        }
        else if ([KeyArray objectAtIndex:i] == @"Type") {
            NSArray *types = [selectedDiamondsFilter objectForKey:[KeyArray objectAtIndex:i]];
            for (int i = 0; i<[types count]; i++) {
                NSLog(@"%@",[types objectAtIndex:i]);
                [[GANTracker sharedTracker] setCustomVariableAtIndex:1 name:@"Type" value:[types objectAtIndex:i] scope:kGANVisitorScope withError:&error];
                if(![[GANTracker sharedTracker] trackEvent:@"Diamond Sort" action:@"Sort selected" label:@"sort" value:-1 withError:nil]){
                    NSLog(@"Not able to track for Diamonds Section");
                }                   
            }

        }

        [[GANTracker sharedTracker] dispatch];

        if (error != nil) {
            NSLog(@"Custom Variable HAS ERROR");
        }

        NSLog(@"%@",selectedDiamondsFilter);
    }
```

but problem is that its updating sometime "Type" sometime "Carat" and sometimes something else.

Please Help me where i m making mistake.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Your comparing pointers, not good.

These all need to be changed to:

```
if([KeyArray objectAtIndex:i] isEqualToString:@"Carat"]])
```